# Hosting Node js application with OVH VPS

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, vps, ovh

I have to hosting my applications ( Node js as a server & Angular-cli ) with ovh vps . I can't find the instructions to follow it .
Is there someone who can help me with a nice tutorial or steps to do it?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Atleast show the documentation that you are having a hard time with.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to your vps using ssh then run on of the following commands that installs node.js

## Node.js only (no dev tools)

#### install node.js without development dependencies

`curl -fsSL bit.ly/node-installer | bash -s --no-dev-deps`

#### using wget instead of curl (Ubuntu)

`wget -nv bit.ly/node-installer -O - | bash -s --no-dev-deps`

## Node.js + dev tools

#### Install node.js and basic development tools - git, node, gcc, pkg-config, etc

`curl -fsSL bit.ly/node-installer -o ./node-installer.sh; bash ./node-installer.sh --dev-deps`

#### using wget instead of curl (Ubuntu)

`wget -nv bit.ly/node-installer -O - ./node-installer.sh; bash ./node-installer.sh --dev-deps`

*Note: bit.ly/node-installer simple redirects to https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/node-installer.sh/raw/master/install.sh*